# How to “autotune” a record sound with Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, cordova, record

I managed to record and play my voice like a dictaphone thanks to Cordova. Now i would like to add an "Autotune" or "Vocoder" effect on my voice, how can i do that ?

PS:I work on mobile device.

Here is the the script for record and play my voice :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0rc1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var deviceready = false;
    var mediaVar = null;
    var recordFileName = "recording.wav";
    var status = null;
    var isIOS = false;

    function onBodyLoad()
    {        
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        deviceready = true;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#stopBtn").hide();
        $("#playBtn").hide();

        //validation to check if device is ready is skipped

        $("#recordBtn").click(function(){
            record();                  
        });

        $("#playBtn").click(function(){
            play();
        });

        $("#stopBtn").click(function(){
            stop();
        });
    });

    function record()
    {
        createMedia(function(){
            status = "recording";
            mediaVar.startRecord();
            $("#recordBtn").hide();
            $("#stopBtn").show();
            $("#playBtn").hide();
        },onStatusChange);
    }

    function createMedia(onMediaCreated, mediaStatusCallback){
        if (mediaVar != null) {
            onMediaCreated();
            return;
        }

        if (typeof mediaStatusCallback == 'undefined') 
            mediaStatusCallback = null;

        if (isIOS) {
            //first create the file
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
                fileSystem.root.getFile(recordFileName, {
                    create: true,
                    exclusive: false
                }, function(fileEntry){
                    log("File " + recordFileName + " created at " + fileEntry.fullPath);
                    mediaVar = new Media(fileEntry.fullPath, function(){
                        log("Media created successfully");
                    }, onError, mediaStatusCallback); //of new Media
                    onMediaCreated();
                }, onError); //of getFile
            }, onError); //of requestFileSystem
        } else //it's Android
        {
            mediaVar = new Media(recordFileName, function(){
                log("Media created successfully");
            }, onError, mediaStatusCallback); 
            onMediaCreated();
        }
    }

    function stop()
    {
        if (mediaVar == null)
            return;

        if (status == 'recording')
        {
            mediaVar.stopRecord();
            log("Recording stopped");
        }
        else if (status == 'playing')
        {
            mediaVar.stop();            
            log("Play stopped");
        } 
        else
        {
            log("Nothing stopped");
        }
        $("#recordBtn").show();
        $("#stopBtn").hide();
        $("#playBtn").show();
        status = 'stopped';
    }

    function play()
    {
        createMedia(function(){
            status = "playing";
            mediaVar.play();    
            $("#recordBtn").hide();
            $("#stopBtn").show();
            $("#playBtn").hide();
        });
    }

    function onStatusChange()
    {
        if (arguments[0] == 4) //play stopped
        {
            $("#recordBtn").show();
            $("#stopBtn").hide();
            $("#playBtn").show();
        } 
    }

    function onSuccess()
    {
        //do nothing
    }

    function onError(err)
    {
        if (typeof err.message != 'undefined')
            err = err.message;
        alert("Error : " + err);
    }

    function log(message)
    {
        if (isIOS)
            console.log(message);
        else
            console.info(message);
    }

    function onDeviceReady()
    {

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pitch detection and manipulation (Autotune is a brand-name for a product Anteres Audio Technology that achieves it) is a hard digital signal processing problem (DSP) which is computationally intensive.

[DPS Dimension](http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/pitch-shifting-using-the-ft/) provides a good tutorial here are about pitch manipulation, but it's very far from being a complete solution.

You are unlikely to make much headway with it without a strong academic background in DSP.    Existing implementations are proprietary and typically implemented in C++. There are many patents in this problem space too.
One option might be to implement the audio processing server-side using a licensed component.

You might have more luck implementing a Vocoder in Javascript - the complexity is lower and there are plenty of algorithms in the public domain to try.

Comment: Ok , thanks you very much ! I will try to implement a Vocoder .

Comment: or is there a web service to apply effect on .mp3 ?

Comment: I don't know of any offering this particular effect, but the idea has definitely been suggested before and is not terribly hard to implement.

Comment: Zplane/sonic api has single voice pitch correction as a web service: http://www.sonicapi.com/docs/api/process-elastiqueTune